# Run parallel loops in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I have two sets of arrays stored in a file and I need to extract values one by one and compare them. I am using this code but does look like I am doing correctly.

```
# First Dataset
File.foreach(file_set_a) do |data_a|

  data_array_a = data_a.split("\t")
  @file_name_a = data_array_a[0]
  @file_ext_a = data_array_a[1]

  # Second Dataset
  File.foreach(file_set_b) do |data_b|

    data_array_b = data_b.split("\t")
    @file_name_b = data_array_b[0]
    @file_ext_b = data_array_b[1]

    #Compare
    @file_name_a == @file_name_b 
  end
end
```

The problem is, I cannot go back and extract the next values in the set A when I enter the set B. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here.  Perhaps give a sample of input data, and what you finally want to do after you "compare" them.  There is probably a better way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

First, convert those 2 files into two separated data arrays

```
lines_array_a = File.readlines(file_set_a)
lines_array_b = File.readlines(file_set_b)
```

I am assuming both of the array size will be same. Now run a loop and get the items from both array to compare them.

```
for i in 0..(lines_array_a.count - 1) do
  data_array_a = lines_array_a[i].split("\t")
  @file_name_a = data_array_a[0]
  @file_ext_a = data_array_a[1]

  data_array_b = lines_array_b[i].split("\t")
  @file_name_b = data_array_b[0]
  @file_ext_b = data_array_b[1]

  @file_name_a == @file_name_b
end
```

Comment: Your solution assumes that the rows are in sync. The original question scans the second file for each `file_a` row to look for a matching line in `file_b`.

Comment: @KimmoLehto The point I tried to make here is to creating data array from those files at first and then play with those data arrays. The cause of the problem _**I cannot go back and extract the next values**_ - is because he was using nested loop, which I tried to avoid in my approach. TIA.

Comment: It could scan the in-memory data of set B for each item in set A to find a matching pair.